# what is only a fiction VS what a fiction only is

Tags: free-relative-clauses

Recently, I`ve stumbled upon an opinion by Slavoy Zizek, that contained a sentence that puzzled me. The sentence was the following:

"Our fundamental delusion today is not believing in what is only a fiction, to take fictions too seriously – on the contrary, it is not taking fictions seriously enough."

The part that confuses me is: "...not believing in what **is** only **a fiction**..." Why is the word order like this? Shouldn`t it be: "...not believing in what **a fiction** only **is**...." ?

Thanks for advance for all your feedback

Answer (score 2):

The *what* at the beginning a free relative clause stands for some term missing from the remainder of the clause. We figure out its referent by analysing the syntax and finding the missing term.

1. > what is only a fiction

   If we ignore the *what*, we're left with *is only a fiction*. Obviously the missing term—let's call it *X*—is the subject of this clause:

   > *X* is only a fiction

   So the author claims that our fundamental delusion is not that we believe in something which is only a fiction, but that we do **not** believe in fictions—we do not take fictions seriously enough.
2. > what only a fiction is

   If, again, we ignore the *what*, we're left with *only a fiction is*. In this case our missing term, *X* is obviously the predicate complement:

   > Only a fiction is *X*.

   In this case we would be looking for something completely different: *X* would be some quality such as "poetic truth" or "imaginative vision" which can only be attributed to a fiction. . . . But that would make no sense in this context, where the author is denying the proposition that belief in *X* is a delusion.

Comment: Maybe others might see things differently (and it might be much clearer as a *spoken* delivery), but I find the cited phrasing inherently "awkward". For me it's a "garden path" construction - I had to back up and reparse after assuming I was being told that our fundamental delusion was ***not** doing X* (i.e. - not doing X is delusional). Eventually it turns out that doing X is ***not*** our fundamental delusion (but by implication, doing X probably ***is*** delusional - it's just not the *most* delusional thing we do).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree: you can't tell whether *not* belongs to *is* or *believing*. However, *isn't* instead of *is not* would be unambiguous.

Comment: Now why didn't ***I*** think of that! I'm going to assume Slavoy Zizek didn't either because (a) he doesn't speak English very well, (b) his *translator* doesn't speak English very well, or (c) either/both of them are no better than me. (You've missed a great career in proofreading! :)